# np.asarray not allowing strings

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following df[image: My DataFrame]

I am trying to measure the distances/similarities between certain rows.

```
import gower
distances = data_test_prepared.iloc[: , 2:]
X = np.asarray(distances)
Y = np.asarray(data_test_prepared)
gower.gower_matrix(X)
```

However, when I run this, I get an error saying:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Malay'
```

I thought np.asarray could accept strings, so I do not know what is wrong here.

***Edit: Resolved in comments***

Comment: Show the full error message, with traceback

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/8h/zm99p5yn0571bvvqzq3r1tfr0000gn/T/ipykernel_5463/2936486722.py in <module>
      3 X = np.asarray(distances)
      4 Y = np.asarray(data_test_prepared)
----> 5 gower.gower_matrix(X)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gower/gower_dist.py in gower_matrix(data_x, data_y, weight, cat_features)
     48 
     49     for col in range(num_cols):

Comment: ---> 50         col_array = Z_num[:, col].astype(np.float32)
     51         max = np.nanmax(col_array)
     52         min = np.nanmin(col_array)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Malay'

Comment: The error says it's  the `gower_matrix` that's expecting a float array.  `nanmax` removes `nan` values, which are floats.

Comment: Put the  traceback in the question, it's easier to read there.

Comment: awesome, thanks. If I wanted to, could I skip the np.asarray and go straight pd.df? and use fillna(0)?

Comment: I don't know what `gower` expects.

Comment: @dmoses you say "Resolved in comments," but the resolution is not clear to me; can you please clarify?